# Using awk to gather network use from a single line in 2 files read at different times

Tags: awk, xfce

To put this simply, I'm trying to build a genmon script that monitors network transfer using awk in a 1-liner to reduce CPU use.

What I'm aiming for is I'd like this script to update every 0.25 seconds.

What I have currently is a 4-line script:

```
PTXRX=( $(awk 'FNR==1' "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/tx_bytes" "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/rx_bytes") )
sleep 0.125
CTXRX=( $(awk 'FNR==1' "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/tx_bytes" "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/rx_bytes") )
awk -v ptx=${PTXRX[0]} -v prx=${PTXRX[1]} -v ctx=${CTXRX[0]} -v crx=${CTXRX[1]} 'BEGIN {printf "tx: %.2f KiB/s\nrx: %.2f KiB/s", (ctx-ptx)/512, (crx-prx)/512 }'
```

`0.125` because the plugin needs time to display the update, so we're approximating in half the time and doubling the value (which isn't too far off).

sample data: (data expected in files)

```
tx_bytes: 284425478
rx_bytes: 3450790917

sleep 0.125

tx_bytes: 284426024
rx_bytes: 3450790917
```

The problem with this is it uses between 10-20% of my CPU...
How can I reduce this to just a single awk command and increase performance??

For those needing a visual to understand what this does, the result should display this:

```
tx: 0.00 KiB/s
rx: 0.00 KiB/s
```

Comment: @EdMorton though trivial, included in just about every linux distro, I provided the extra info regardless, and yes I did mean `/` instead of `\\` not sure what came over me there to mess that up so bad, thanks, typo corrected.

Comment: I just corrected a typo in that as well before reading your comment, I was talking about tx_bytes and rx_bytes, they're not that hard to look up, and *should* contain the same information on any linux distro (that is, if that core functionality exists in said distro).

Comment: that's why I provided, strictly for the ease

Comment: that's any number between 0 and possibly 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF unless larger is allowed (I have a 64bit system at least) provided on a single line as the number of bytes transferred during at least the system uptime (I really hope it's not the total bytes transferred since OS installation). I can't provide a value for something expected to be dynamic, so the best I can do is a description and expect people to test with their own systems (or just guess any value between the unsigned 64bit range).

Comment: full data example provided (results taken from actual files)

Comment: I believe I've provided a decent sample in the edit, the spacing can be anywhere from 0 bytes to 1.6MiB (~over 100Mb limited by the adapter this PC is connected to), so with 0 bytes on the rx and almost a KB on the tx, it should be pretty decent for being non-busy. And yes, the 2nd eighth of a second is discarded to allow room for processing, if you can recommend better for accuracy, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192523/discussion-between-tcll-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IFS= read -r ptx < "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/tx_bytes"
IFS= read -r prx < "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/rx_bytes"
sleep 0.125
IFS= read -r ctx < "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/tx_bytes"
IFS= read -r crx < "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/rx_bytes"
awk -v ptx="$ptx" -v prx="$prx" -v ctx="$ctx" -v crx="$crx" 'BEGIN {printf "tx: %.2f KiB/s\nrx: %.2f KiB/s\n", (ctx-ptx)/512, (crx-prx)/512 }'
```

If that doesn't help then you can't fix your performance problem in this code segment and you'll have to reconsider your approach of looping and calling commands every 0.125 secs.

If you're using bash you could replace the remaining call to awk with:

```
printf 'tx: %.2f KiB/s\nrx: %.2f KiB/s\n' $(( (ctx-ptx)/512 )) $(( (crx-prx)/512 ))
```

but it's still not going to make a significant difference.

One last thing you could try that MAY squeeze slightly better performance out of it (or it may even be worse but you can try it):

```
IFS= read -r ptx < "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/tx_bytes"
IFS= read -r prx < "/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/rx_bytes"
sleep 0.125
awk -v ptx="$ptx" -v prx="$prx" -v tx_bytes="/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/tx_bytes" -v rx_bytes="/sys/class/net/${1}/statistics/rx_bytes" 'BEGIN{
    getline ctx < tx_bytes
    getline crx < rx_bytes
    printf "tx: %.2f KiB/s\nrx: %.2f KiB/s\n", (ctx-ptx)/512, (crx-prx)/512
}'
```

Comment: I tested both yours and oguz's (now deleted) answer respectively, his answer used roughly 7-11% of my CPU while yours uses roughly 3-8%. Nice job

Comment: That still seems like a lot of CPU being used up but I'm glad you're happy with it.

Comment: there's a few things it could be: number of commands executed, bash data handling `$(( ))`, `xfce4-genmon-plugin` but I believe this is probably about as good as it gets on this potato CPU (Pentium4 +HT, feel free to laugh)